# "pointer being freed was not allocated" in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, while-loop

I am writing a program that reads lines from a file.
But when I execute it I get this error:

```c
#include "get_next_line.h"

void ft_memdel(void **ap)
{
    if (ap != NULL)
    {
        free(*ap);
        *ap = NULL;
    }
}
void ft_strdel(char **as)
{
    if (as != NULL && *as != NULL)
        ft_memdel((void**)as);
}

static int appendline(char **s, char **line)
{
    int len;
    char *tmp;

    len = 0;
    while ((*s)[len] != '\n' && (*s)[len] != '\0')
        len++;
    if ((*s)[len] == '\n')
    {
        *line = ft_substr(*s, 0, len);
        tmp = ft_strdup(&((*s)[len + 1]));
        free(*s);
        *s = tmp;
        if ((*s)[0] == '\0')
            ft_strdel(s);
    }
    else
    {
        *line = ft_strdup(*s);
        ft_strdel(s);
    }
    return (1);
}

static int output(char **s, char **line, int ret, int fd)
{
    if (ret < 0)
        return (-1);
    else if (ret == 0 && s[fd] == NULL)
        return (0);
    else
        return (appendline(&s[fd], line));
}

int get_next_line(const int fd, char **line)
{
    int         ret;
    static char *s[FD_SIZE];
    char        buff[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    char        *tmp;

    if (fd < 0 || line == NULL || !fd)
        return (-1);
    while ((ret = read(fd, buff, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        buff[ret] = '\0';
        if (s[fd] == NULL)
            s[fd] = ft_strdup(buff);
        else
        {
            tmp = ft_strjoin(s[fd], buff);
            free(s[fd]);
            s[fd] = tmp;
        }
        if (ft_strchr(s[fd], '\n'))
            break ;
    }
    return (output(s, line, ret, fd));
}
```

The `BUFF SIZE` variable is set in my `.h` file and the program should work with any size except negative or 0.

```
a.out(51676,0x10ef9a5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb2e9402ea0: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(51676,0x10ef9a5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
run2.sh: line 3: 51676 Abort trap: 6           ./a.out
```

Comment: Why not "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug", then? That seems faster than making readers wade through all that code they don't know to figure out what you did wrong. And I vote to close because this isn't a complete example, i.e. no `main()` and call from same.

Comment: Could you at least use gdb or similar to work out which of the frees is the problem? And do all of the strings come from strdup? And you're not modifying any of the pointers between allocation and free are you? (I can't see that here at first glance though)

Comment: Add a main to have underscore_d happy, then people here can help you better (running it for you with a debugger for instance)